# How can I get css property of an element which clicked in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

Here is some `A` elements in blazor server-side:

```
<div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Add" @onclick="SingleAddClick">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Add" @onclick="SingleAddClick">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Add" @onclick="SingleAddClick">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Add" @onclick="SingleAddClick">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Add" @onclick="SingleAddClick">
</div>
```

All the position of the `A` elements above is absolute. The `Left` and `Top` are differing from each `A` element.

Now when an `A` element is clicked, I wanna get the `Left` and `Top` of its position.

I need to transfer the js object from .Net method to JS method by `JS interop` while I don't know how to get the JS object in .Net method.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture a reference to your element as follows:

```
<a @ref="anchorElement" href="javascript:void(0)" class="Add" 
                                                @onclick="SingleAddClick"> 

@code
{
    private ElementReference anchorElement;
}
```

Now you can call a JSInterop method and pass it the element reference. You should use it in your JS method as though it was retrieved by the getElementById method.

Note: You shouldn't use JavaScript in Blazor. Use `@onclick:preventDefault` instead of `href="javascript:void(0)"`

I hope that helps! If you get stuck, let me know

Comment: The ElementReference is the best choice!

Answer (score 1):

In-order to identify *left* and *top*, you'll need to provide a unique identifier (uid) to your every anchor tags. Your uid can either be a `ElementReference` or a just static (hard-coded) name. With this uid you can identity from where the event is raised from then search it in dom to find relative position to the viewport.

Below are the changes you will need to do to get the *elements* left and *top* position.

> Razor Component

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime // need to inject IJSRuntime to invoke a JavaScript function.

<a id="anchor1" href="" class="Add" @onclick='() => SingleAddClick("anchor1")' @onclick:preventDefault>

@code{

    private async Task SingleAddClick(string clickedElementId)
    {
        //your existing code

        // call the javacript method that will be returing something.
        var dimensions = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getDimensions", clickedElementId);

        // I've used a dynamic type object so that I don't need to create a custom class to desealize it.
        dynamic d = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(dimensions);

        // Since I've used dynamic keyword thus the type will get resolved at runtime. 
        // Will throw exception if d is null thus need to be handled properly.
        string top = d.top;
        string left = d.left;
    }
}
```

> JS Library

If you are using any existing js file for interop service then add below javascript method else create a new js file and reference it in *_host.*

```
function getDimensions(element) {
    return JSON.stringify(document.getElementById(element).getBoundingClientRect());
}
```

Note: The [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.